# ListBoxItem Trigger.Exit behavior inside OnSelectionChanged event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ListBox with 5 items (years). When user select last item, i want to shift ListBox items one year forward, but keep selection on the year user clicked on:

2011 2012 2013 2014 **2015** should turn to 2012 2013 2014 **2015** 2016.

I'm doing it through messing with underlying ViewModels:

```
private void Calendar_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_calendarUpdateInProgress) return;
        _calendarUpdateInProgress = true;

    var cvm = YearsListBox.SelectedItem as CalendarElementViewModel;
    if (cvm != null)
    {
        int year = cvm.Year; //year I would like to keep selected
        VM.ShiftYear(year);  //change year properties of viewmodels in ItemsSource
        YearsListBox.UnselectAll();
        foreach (CalendarElementViewModel item in YearsListBox.Items)
        {
            if (item.Year == year)
            {
                YearsListBox.SelectedItem = item;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I get now is 2012 2013 2014 **2015** **2016** and it seems that this ListBoxItem style trigger doesn't fire on unselection:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
  <Trigger.EnterActions>
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnSelected}" />
  </Trigger.EnterActions>
  <Trigger.ExitActions>
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnUnSelected}" />
  </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

YearsListBox have one actual selected item (2015), as expected. I've tried to trace ListBoxItem Selected and Unselected events - they are firing in correct order as well. When I try to change selection between non-border items, they are deselected properly.
What happens here and why last item is not updated properly? Is it because i'm changing selection while already in the OnSelectionChanged?

Comment: Usually when I use a listbox with a single row selection I bind 2 ways the SelectedItem to a property of my model and managing that property I can control what is selected both from the UI or from code depending on what I am doing

Comment: Yes, i just tried that, but essentially it's kind of same problem - I'd need to modify the value while inside of the property setter called by the UI event. Result is the same - selection changes, but UI is not updated.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not really possible to know for sure what the issue in your code is. If you want a good answer, please provide a good code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working on the minimal code example i noticed that the default-styled ListBoxItem will not exhibit such behaviour. Difference is in the way of handling selection state - style I use does it via `<Trigger Property="IsSelected">` and its Trigger.ExitAction just would not fire.

Default ListBoxItem uses VisualStateManager, which works correctly in my circumstances. While it's not quite an answer to my initial question, it is good enough workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the values of the viewmodels complicates things it requires you to move your selection which also triggers the selectionchanged again.

Try something like this:

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;
    if (listBox.SelectedIndex == this.YearListBox.Count - 1)
    {
        this.YearListBox.Add(new CalendarElementViewModel() { Year = this.YearListBox.Last().Year + 1 });
        this.YearListBox.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Also you can use visibility property of the listboxitems to hide years.

Comment: I'm using bool flag to avoid triggering selectionChanged again and blowing the stack - it is in the code.

Recreating listbox items will help in this case, because new items will be created in unselected state - but i wanted to reuse them, because it creates a small but noticeable hiccup when you do it for 30+ items.